# Ember.Js: How to link back to TextField with Model Property

Tags: ember.js

I have model:

```
App.Wizard = Em.Object.extend({
    title:'example',   
});
```

I have View:

```
var wizardView = Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'wizard'  

});
```

The template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="wizard">
    <label>
       <span>Title</span>
          {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="App.Wizard.title" }}
     </label>
</script>
```

On page i can see input with text from my model, but when i changed text on input, then vulue from App.Wizard.title not was changed.

How connection input to model field?

Comment: did my answer work for you? let me know if not so I can improve it further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for a working example: http://jsbin.com/aqetef/3/edit
Try to change the text in the input field and see it updating in the label below.

Basically this is code:

```
App.Wizard = Em.Object.extend({
  title:'example'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('wizard', {path: '/'});
});

App.WizardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Wizard.create({title: 'Foo'});
  }
});
```

And since we are now providing a model object for the rendered view/template you can define the binding using the actual context which is the new model object created.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="wizard">
  <label>
    <span>Title</span>
      {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="title"}}
  </label>
  <hr/>
  {{title}}
</script>
```

Also worth mentioning is that if you have nothing rendering related to do in your view you don't need to define one.

Hope it helps.